# Finding $E(X\mid X>Y)$ when $X,Y$ are i.i.d $U(0,1)$

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

[image]

I am unable to compute conditional probability(x|x>y) in the above question. Also, I am unable to determine the region of integration for calculation of the above expectation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least two ways to find this quantity:

- $E\left[X\mid X>Y\right]=E\left[\max(X,Y)\right]$ (use the distribution of $\max(X,Y)$)
- $E\left[X\mid X>Y\right]=\frac{1}{P(X>Y)}E\left[X\mathbf1_{X>Y}\right]$ (by definition)

In the second method, courtesy of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) theorem,  you have

\begin{align}
E\left[X\mathbf1_{X>Y}\right]&=\iint x\mathbf1_{x>y}\mathbf1_{0<x,y<1}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
\\&=\int_0^1 \int_y^1 x\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
\end{align}

And since $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d continuous, $P(X>Y)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: In the second method you mentioned above, what would be the region of integration for the expectation?

Comment: @Jor_El How about now? This double integral can be calculated simply by drawing a picture, if you are having trouble with direct evaluation.

Comment: The numeric answer you give is inconsistent with the first approach. The mean of the distribution of max(X,Y) is (plainly) greater than 1/2. The correct answer to the question is 2/3.

Comment: @Glen_b I don't think this question actually gives an answer: consistent with our [tag:self-study] policy, it provides guidance and partial results towards an answer.

Comment: @Glen_b  Both methods give 2/3 as far as I see.

Comment: My apologies; I misread the thing being evaluated at the end.