# Conditional Mean E[X|X>Y] when X,Y are Uniform

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions

X and Y are independent and identically distributed uniform (0,1) random variables.
Find E(X|X>Y)
Please explain it step by step.
I am getting ans 0.5 while the actual answer given is 0.66

Comment: please show the steps you have tried to get to 0.5

Comment: The unconditional mean is 0.5, which should have caused you to question your answer. Also, you should give how you found 0.5, to help us spot your mistake. I'll be able to explain my answer as well if you do so, since otherwise it'll be a complete solution which isn't in line with answers for self-study questions.

Comment: Asked before: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/398542/119261. Please see the `self-study` tag [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) which requires you to show your work.

Answer (score 0):

A simple graphical approach is via using just x-y plane. These variables are independent, so their joint is defined over the square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$. This region shows us all possible pairs of $(X,Y)$ When $X>Y$ is given as event, we should focus on the region *below* the line $X=Y$, where it contains $(X,Y)$ pairs having the desired ordering. So, your interested region is a triangle with corners $\{(0,0),(1,0),(1,1)\}$. What is the center of mass of this triangle, and what is its x coordinate?

Comment: X co ordinate is 2/3 but how the problem is related to centre of mass of that triangle.Is it because that point is centroid of the triangle and hence the conditional mean?

Comment: this integral should result in the answer: E(X | X > Y) = $\int_{y}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} dy  dx $. I didn't bother to calculate it. It should be doing the same thing that the other people described geometrically.

Comment: @mlofton, actually it is $$\int_0^1\int_y^12xdxdy=\int_0^1\int_0^x2xdydx$$

Comment: @gunes: Thanks but where does the 2  come from ? I realize that I forgot the $x$ in the expected value but I'm not clear on the 2. Wisdom appreciated.

Comment: It is the value of the PDF, in the triangular region, i.e. $f(x,y)$.

Comment: @gunes:  just to confirm my understanding: since the area of the triangle is 1/2, then the conditional pdf has to be equal to  2 because it has to sum to 1 over the whole triangular region. thanks.

Comment: yes, also your limits changed slightly if you noticed.

Comment: thanks for explanation.